# What are standard ways for an editor to specify he is making a correction?

Tags: quotations

Suppose I am a reporter quoting someone, or an editor for someone's article. The original speaker/writer has made a mistake and I want to correct it in the edited version (while still being true to the original). What are standard ways to do that?

That's kind of a reverse "sic" - I use sic when I want to keep the mistake intact, what should I use when I don't?

I thought about using S/B for "should be", e.g. "What a beautiful green (S/B blue) sky", but I'm not sure this will be widely understood.

I also know of a practice of specifying the editor's initials, e.g. "What a beautiful green (blue. MR) sky", but in my context people aren't necessarily supposed to know the editor's name.

Comment: You could use your second suggestions and not put the initials of the editor but just _editor's note_. E.g. "What a beautiful green (blue. _editor's note_) sky"

Comment: @jera Thanks. But I'm looking for something more compact.

Comment: Is it *necessary* that you alert the reader to the original text (*green*, in the example)? If so, I can't help thinking you should include significantly more text (additional sentence or footnote) explaining *why* you've made the change, but that would be a fairly unusual situation. If you *don't* need that, just enclose your revision in square brackets: *What a beautiful [blue] sky!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In a way, yes. The exact situation I have is slightly more complicated than I described, but to make a long story short I strongly prefer that 1. The original word appears. 2. The correction appears. 3. It is clear that it is a correction. 4. This is done as concisely as possible. I might consider your suggestion if no better alternative is found, though.

Comment: Traditionally, in newspapers, editors used a [blue pencil](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/blue_pencil_(editing)) to correct mistakes. Nowadays, editing articles is done electronically so scribbling is made redundant. The only vestige of this I can think of is *Private Eye*'s fake corrections used for comedic effect, which take the form of *Shurely this is wrong Ed.* etc. (S**h**urely is alluding to editors' habit for a liquid lunch) *Private Eye* is a very traditional paper in many ways and was born to satire newspapers, as such, their "Ed." notes are probably historically accurate.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I think you'll find that this was one of the Eye's regular jibes, more accurately framed as, "Shurely some mistake, Ed". Moreover, it was a mimic-in-print of Bill Deedes, onetime editor of the Daily Telegraph and an indefatigable TV-pundit, who pronounced "surely" as "shurely", a sort of Churchillian way of pronouncing words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic#Recte), you **would** use *sic*. For your correction you would use *recte*:

> Alternatively, when both the original and the suggested correction are desired to be shown, one may give the actual form, followed by *sic* in brackets, followed by the corrected form, preceded by *recte*, in brackets. The word *recte* is a Latin adverb meaning "rightly".
>
> > An Iraqi battalion has consumed [sic] [recte assumed] control of the former American military base, and our forces are now about 40 minutes outside the city.

The format may change depending on what style you follow. For example:

> He was married to Ida Stigman at Emmetsburg, Iowa in 1905 [sic, recte 1906]. She passed away in 1919 [sic, recte 1918]. He was married to Ida Rosental [sic, recte Rosenthal] in 1924 [sic, recte 1922]. She passed away in 1932 [sic, recte 1930]. He then married Mary Perry at Fairmont, Minnesota on September 15, 1935. She passed away in 1960 [sic, recte 1958].
>
> <sub>[Obituary for William C. Schutt](https://familysearch.org/photos/artifacts/25136590)</sub>